# Background image Class

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm using Wpbakery

1. I want to add FadeInUp animation to the background image only, and not on entire row elements. How can I do this?
2. Is there a way to give class to only the background image?
3. How can I control the speed of animation?

Comment: Please show a simple snippet demonstrating the problem. Try putting the background in a pseudo element and styling that.

Answer (score 0):

1. I want to add FadeInUp animation to the background image only, and not on entire row elements. How can I do this?

To give an animation to the background only you need to separate it out from the main element. This can be done with a pseudo element which is given the same dimensions as the element and placed behind it.

2. Is there a way to give class to only the background image?

Once you have the pseudo element in place you can style that independently from the actual element.

3. How can I control the speed of animation?

The time taken for the animation is controlled through the animation-duration setting.

```css
.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 20vh;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
}

.container::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1016/300/300);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  animation-name: fadeInUp;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  z-index: -1;
}

@keyframes fadeInUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>A HEADING</h1>
</div>
```